# How to translate an ListBoxItem with firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, translation, firemonkey, listboxitem, delphi-xe5

I have a listbox populated form a database table. I want to add a last item called "Go back" and I add it from the source code in this way:

```
lbDGroup.Items.Add('GO BACK');
```

I have a TLang component with the "GO BACK" string translated into another languages, but this item it's not transalted (it always shows "GO BACK").

How can I set it to be translated with TLang (all components added from design and all showmessages are shown correctly translated).

Thank's

Comment: Did you add a language entry for `GO BACK`? Please show how you're "populating" the listbox, so we can recreate the issue.

Comment: If you hard-code it to say "GO BACK", why would you expect it to change? The ones that are changing are properly using properties that can be automatically replaced; you're using a constant string embedded in your code, which is not anywhere near the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the current translated text programmatically of your GO BACK Source :

```
var
  dGOBACK: string;
begin
  dGOBACK := Lang1.LangStr[Lang1.Lang].Values['GO BACK'];
  lbDGroup.Items.Add(dGOBACK);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

easier:

```
uses
  FMX.Types;

begin
  lbDGroup.Items.Add(Translate('GO BACK'));
end;
```

on Delphi FMX XE6 and above